# Pegar valor de data-value que é gerado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou precisando pegar o valor de um data-attr que é gerado de uma requisição ajax.

O máximo que aonde cheguei foi:

```
$('.dataImposto').on('click', '.ImpostodeRenda', function(){
    $(".ImpostodeRenda").html("ooi");
});
```

O problema está em que esse "ImpostodeRenda" é gerado dinamicamente a partir de um retorno de um ajax.

**Retorno do Ajax**

```
dados = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(dados,function (key) {
    $(".dataImposto").append(" <div class='row static-info align-reverse'> <div class='col-md-8 name '>"+dados[key].nome+" ("+dados[key].valor+"%)</div> <div i class='col-md-3 value  imposto "+dados[key].nome.replace( /\s/g, '' ) + "' data-class="+dados[key].nome.replace( /\s/g, '' )+" data-imposto="+dados[key].valor+" > </div> </div>");
});
```

**Exemplo de HTML gerado**

```html
<div class="dataImposto">
  <div class="row static-info align-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-8 name "> DAS(11.50 % )
    </div>
    <div id="imposto" class="col-md-3 value DAS" data-class="DAS" data-imposto="11.50"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row static-info align-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-8 name ">Imposto de Renda (15.00%)</div>
    <div id="imposto" class="col-md-3 value ImpostodeRenda" data-class="ImpostodeRenda" data-imposto="15.00">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Olha que é gerado DAS...

Queria pegar o data-class e o data-imposto de ambos.

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é bem simples, você usa o `document` para se referenciar já que o `DOM` já foi carregado.

```js
$('#gerar').on('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<button class="classeQueTereiEmTodos" data-value="OI">Get</button>')
})

$(document).on('click', '.classeQueTereiEmTodos', function(){
   var valor = $(this).attr('data-value')
   
   alert(valor)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="gerar">Gerar attr</button>
```

Comment: Legal, mas acontece o seguinte.

Tenho uma div com "dataImposto" o conteúdo do retorno do ajax é colocado dentro do dessa div, com o código que eu mostrei acima. Esse ajax é enviado quando aperto um botão. 

Eu queria que pegasse o valor do data-value assim que clicasse no botão

Comment: Você quer enviar esse valor como parametro do ajax?

Comment: Não, quero resgatar o valor do data-attr que vem criado com o retorno do ajax, dentro da div

Comment: Então, é só fazer do jeito que fiz a cima. Caso mesmo assim não tenha funcionado, me explique melhor que te ajudo a resolver.

Comment: Ta na minha hora de pra aula, tudo bem te chamar amanha? tem skype ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Veio, bom dia, Cheguei te adicionar no Skype

Comment: Tive que fazer uma pequena adaptação mas a ideia de pegar um que já existe pra todos funcionou legal